How to run multiple async testcases using AsyncClient and pytest?
Here are two async testcases:
here is first async testcase
@pytest.mark.asyncio async def test_create_location(db_session, async_client: AsyncClient):`

`async with db_session() as session:

    stmt = await session.execute(select(Countries))
    result = stmt.scalars().all()
    country_id = result[0].country_id`

test_create_data = [

        {
            "name": "albama",
            "keywords": "us",
            "email": "google.tech@outlook.com",
            "telephone": 9874586324,
            "telephone_code": 92,
            "street_address": " Enclave GT Road",
            "address_locality": "new area",
            "postal_code": 211101,
            "address_country": str(country_id),
            "address_region": "america",
            "description": "nothing to write here"
        },
        {"status_code": 201},
        {"message": "Location saved successfully"}


]

# async with db_session as session:
response = await async_client.put("/api/v1/location", json=test_create_data[0])

assert response.status_code == test_create_data[1]["status_code"]
assert  response.json()["message"]== test_create_data[2]["message"]

async with db_session() as session:

    stmt = await session.execute(
        select(func.count()).select_from(Location).where
        (
            Location.address_country == country_id,
            Location.name == test_create_data[0]["name"],
            Location.address_locality == test_create_data[0]["address_locality"],
            Location.address_region == test_create_data[0]["address_region"],
            Location.description == test_create_data[0]["description"],
            Location.email == test_create_data[0]["email"],
            Location.postal_code == test_create_data[0]["postal_code"],
            Location.telephone == test_create_data[0]["telephone"],
            Location.telephone_code == test_create_data[0]["telephone_code"],
            Location.street_address == test_create_data[0]["street_address"],
            Location.keywords == test_create_data[0]["keywords"],


        )
    )
    assert stmt.scalar() == 1, 'there should be only one matching Location record'



'''  -------------------------------------- Test Negative Unprocessable Data ----------------------------------  '''
and then it is second async testcase
test_negative_data = [
(

        {
            "name": "St Petersberg",
            "keywords": "Rus",
            "email": "techno9@outlook.com",
            "telephone": 8474586324,
            "telephone_code": 91,
            "street_address": "four square enclave",
            "address_locality": "city center",
            "postal_code": 54871,
            "address_country": str(uuid.uuid4()),
            "address_region": "South block",
            "description": "NA to write"
        },
        409

)

]

@pytest.mark.asyncio
@pytest.mark.parametrize('payload, status_code', test_negative_data)
async def test_negative_unprocessable_country(db_session, async_client: AsyncClient, payload, status_code):
response = await async_client.put("/api/v1/location", json=payload)

assert response.status_code == status_code`

**   and i am using pytest for performing unit testing and that's why can't use asyncio.gather() and
i also switched from TestClient to HTTPX.AsyncClient still getting same error of attached to a different loop**
